# Dynamically changing the text in hyperlink with Vue JS 2

Tags: data-binding, hyperlink, vuejs2

I am trying to create an empty hyperlink, which will trigger a method when clicking. However, for an unknown reason, the method is called but the text is not binding.
You can copy and try at the address: https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/okv0rgrk/

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Edit'
    },
    methods: {
     edit() {
            message: 'Done'
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click="edit()" id="app">
  {{message}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't accessing the Vue instance's data property correctly.

A Vue instance's data properties are set up via the `data` property (or more commonly `data` method), but then are directly accessible on the instance via `this`.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            message: 'Edit'
        }
    },
    methods: {
     edit() {
            this.message = 'Done';
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click="edit()" id="app">
  {{message}}
</a>
```